# Better way to segment aggregated data in Pandas?

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

I am trying to group on two columns to get an aggregated value and then test that value to see if it is greater or smaller than a threshold. What I have:

```
SEGMENT = df.groupby(['Col_1','Col_2'])['Number'].apply(lambda x: '1_5' if sum(x) <6 else '6+'
```

It is slow. Is there a fundamental error in this approach? Thanks.

Edit:

```
SEGMENT = df.groupby(['Col_1','Col_2'])['Number'].sum().apply(lambda x: '1_5' if x <6 else '6+'
```

This is speeds it up 3x.

Comment: Is it faster if you use `x.sum()` instead of `sum(x)`?

Comment: It is faster if I do the above. I will try x.sum() to. Thanks

Comment: x.sum is marginally faster, the method in the edit is quickest so far

Comment: You really want to return a bool to indicate rather than a string. Also avoiding apply where possible.

Comment: Thanks for your help @AndyHayden I didn't understand that the group by object retains all the other dimensions. I think I do now. In the filter example how would I get the group by object back to a dataframe?

Comment: @JBradley filter should return a DataFrame, perhaps need to use g["Number"].filter if it's not (weird)

Comment: @AndyHayden g['Number'].filter returns a series, but g[['Number']].filter returns a frame. Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do a [transform](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) and use it as a boolean mask:

```
g = df.groupby(['Col_1','Col_2'])

mask = g["Number"].transform("sum") < 6

df[mask]  # with group sum smaller than 6
df[~mask]  # with group sum greater or equal 6
```

You're can also use [filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
g.filter(lambda x: x.sum() >= 6)
```